# Django modal popup on a list link

Tags: python, django, modal-dialog, popup

I would like to develop a popup on a list link (please see the screenshot) click. popup will be a list also.
So far this is my code below
Model class:

```
class PSCInscpection(models.Model):
    vessel = models.ForeignKey(Vessel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    inspection_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, unique=True)
    followup_inspection = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    port = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    number_of_defects = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    days_detained = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class PSCInscpectionDefects(models.Model):
    pscinscpection = models.ForeignKey(PSCInscpection, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)    
    inspection_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    defect_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    defect_text = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    class_is_responsible = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    defective_item_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
inspections = PSCInscpection.objects.filter(
        vessel_id=self.kwargs['pk']).order_by('-date')
    renderableInspections = []
    for _insp in inspections:            
        item = {
            "date": _insp.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
            "port": _insp.port,
            "country": _insp.country,
            "defects": _insp.number_of_defects,
            "detained": _insp.days_detained
        }
        renderableInspections.append(item)
    context['inspections'] = renderableInspections
```

My list binding from this "PSCInscpection" object and popup will bind from "PSCInscpectionDefects" object. Any help regarding please ? Thanks !

view.html:

```
{% for inspection in inspections %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ inspection.date }}</td>
          <td>{{ inspection.country }}</td>
          <td>{{ inspection.port }}</td>
          <td>
            {% if inspection.defects %}
              <a href="#">{{ inspection.defects }}</a>
            {% else %}
            {{ 0 }}
            {% endif %}
          </td>
          <td>{{ inspection.detained|default:0 }} Days</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the defects tied to each inspection through the reverse foreign key relationship, but currently you can't do that because the context you're sending to the template is not the queryset of objects itself. Instead, you constructed a data structure manually to handle this which isn't necessary.

You should send the context as your object queryset so you can access your reverse foreign key relationship directly in the template with `inspections.pscinscpectiondefects_set.all`. This is very verbose, so I recommend setting a related_name attribute to the `pscinscpection` field in your `PSCInscpectionDefects` model to `defects` or similar so you can instead access it with `inspections.defects.all`.

Simplify your view to return the filtered queryset instead.

```
# views.py

context['inspections'] = PSCInscpection.objects.filter(
        vessel_id=self.kwargs['pk']).order_by('-date')
return context
```

I won't provide HTML/CSS/JS code for the modal because this question is Django related. But you should be able to launch one when the user clicks the link to the number of defects. Here's the template change assuming a related_name is set.

```
# view.html

{% for inspection in inspections %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ inspection.date }}</td>
          <td>{{ inspection.country }}</td>
          <td>{{ inspection.port }}</td>
          <td>
      
      {% if inspection.defects %}
        <a href="#">{{ inspection.defects.count }}</a> <!-- link to modal here -->
        {% for defect in inspection.defects.all %}
          {{ defect }}
        {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
        {{ 0 }}
      {% endif %}
    </td>
    <td>{{ inspection.detained|default:0 }} Days</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Could you send HTML/CSS/JS code please.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have any.